# How to reduce the size of a git repository using bfg

Tags: git, github, bfg-repo-cleaner

I have a git repository that weighs around 5g. The .git directory weighs 4.5G itself.

My goal is to remove all big files from this history in order to don't have 5G to download when doing a clone.

To do that I wanted to use the BFG open-source tool.

I used these commands :

```
java -jar bfg-1.14.0.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 1M my-repo/.git 
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git push --force
```

My local .git directory go down from 4.5GB to 0.8GB. I checked the file deleted according to the BFG logs and it was ok to me.
The problem is that despite the push --force, when I clone the directory again it's still downloading ~ 4.5GB and this is what I want to avoid. How should I do ?

Comment: For me you force pushed only current branch. You should do the same for all the branches to update all the remotes that could point to old updated commits.

Comment: I did that on a fork of the original repository (so maybe It has an impact for this use case ?). And I also deleted all branches on the fork except the master on which I did the operation before.

Comment: With what you did it should be good but indeed, the fact that it is a fork could have an impact (because GitHub sort of pool/share git objects between forks. The other possibility is that it is an asynchronous  process that garbage collect and repack git objects on GitHub servers. So perhaps it could take time. The better test would be to push your new cleaned repo in another freshly cleaned repo for test and see if it at least work there...