# Migrating a GitLab repository with large files into GitHub while maintaining both upstreams

Tags: git

I have access to a GitLab repository that I need to migrate into GitHub. I need to be able to pull changes from the GitLab repository and push those to GitHub, while still working on the GitHub repository in a different new branch.

So, I pulled the repo from GitLab, added my GitHub remote upstream, created a new branch and tried to push the new branch to GitHub.

The problem is, they pushed a `node_modules.zip` (in a subfolder) on one of the earliest commits into the GitLab upstream and this file is over 200MB in size.

I know that I need Git LFS to support those files, but since the files are already in the history of the GitLab upstream, I cannot migrate to Git LFS without losing the upstream, I think. I was thinking about just getting rid about those files, because I don't need need files that I can get with `npm i` real quick.

Since I don't need the master branch on GitHub at all, I was hoping to rewrite the history on my new branch, but I have problems to figure out how this can be done.

The very important part is that I am able to pull new commits from GitLab, merge them to my own branch and push my own branch to GitHub.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

History, in any Git repository, is nothing more or less than the set of commits in that repository (as found by starting from some branch names, tag names, and/or other names and working backwards, the way Git does in general).  Commits themselves hold full snapshots of *every* file, plus metadata; the metadata hold the hash IDs of previous commits; and the resulting chains of commits form [Merkle trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) which guarantee the validity of the commits.

> The problem is, they pushed a `node_modules.zip` (in a subfolder) on one of the earliest commits into the GitLab upstream and this file is over 200MB in size.

Which of course exceeds the GitHub maximum size.  So *this* commit *cannot* be sent to GitHub.

> Since I don't need the master branch at all, I was hoping to rewrite the history on my new branch, but I have problems to figure out how this can be done.

The rewrite is not difficult (use a tool such as filter-branch, filter-repo, or the [BFG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66763017/1256452)).  But once the rewrite is done, this is a *completely new chain of commits:* a *different* Merkle tree.  It is a different history.  It can be used with itself, but if it is combined with the original history, what you now have is a tree that requires *both* histories to be valid and complete.

> The very important part is that I am able to pull new commits from GitLab, merge them to my own branch and push my own branch to GitHub.

The short version of all of this is "you can't".

The longer version is that you can, but only by *maintaining a parallel history* and *never combining your history with their history*.  This is messy, ugly, painful, and difficult or impossible to automate.  There are as far as I know no tools for doing this.  You use one repository (e.g., on your own machine) that has both histories in it, and another (on GitHub) that has only your rewritten history.  When they have new commits, you cherry-pick them to your own history.  How you keep track of which commits are new-to-your-history is up to you: this is where a tool would come in handy.  Such tools *might* exist, or you could write one.  A barely-adequate one is probably not hard to write, but a good one would be hard.

Comment: Useful information, despite not being fulfilling. I was hoping it is possible to maintain two branches with separate history in one repository and still allowing them to merge to each other without patching or cherry picking, but at least I have a clearer picture about the situation and what must be done, now.